# AWS EMR using spark steps in cluster mode. Application application_ finished with failed status

Tags: apache-spark, aws-cli, amazon-emr, spark-submit

I'm trying to launch a cluster using AWS Cli. I use the following command:

```
aws emr create-cluster --name "Config1" --release-label emr-5.0.0 --applications Name=Spark --use-default-role --log-uri 's3://aws-logs-813591802533-us-west-2/elasticmapreduce/' --instance-groups InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m1.medium InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=2,InstanceType=m1.medium
```

The cluster is created successfully. Then I add this command:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id ID_CLUSTER --region us-west-2 --steps Name=SparkSubmit,Jar="command-runner.jar",Args=[spark-submit,--deploy-mode,cluster,--master,yarn,--executor-memory,1G,--class,Traccia2014,s3://tracceale/params/scalaProgram.jar,s3://tracceale/params/configS3.txt,30,300,2,"s3a://tracceale/Tempi1"],ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE
```

After some time, the step failed. This is the LOG file:

```
 17/02/22 11:00:07 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-  31-190.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.31.190:8032
 17/02/22 11:00:08 INFO Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 2 NodeManagers
 17/02/22 11:00:08 INFO Client: Verifying our application has not requested  
 Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1487760984275_0001 finished with failed status
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1132)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1175)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:729)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
 17/02/22 11:01:02 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
 17/02/22 11:01:02 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-27baeaa9-8b3a-4ae6-97d0-abc1d3762c86
 Command exiting with ret '1'
```

Locally (on SandBox Hortonworks HDP 2.5) I run:

```
./spark-submit --class Traccia2014 --master local[*] --executor-memory 2G /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/ScalaProjects/ScripRapportoBatch2.1/target/scala-2.11/traccia-22-ottobre_2.11-1.0.jar "/home/tracce/configHDFS.txt" 30 300 3
```

and everything works fine.
I've already read something related to my problem, but I can't figure it out.

**UPDATE**

Checked into Application Master, I get this error:

```
17/02/22 15:29:54 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: s3:/tracceale/params/configS3.txt (No such file or directory)

at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:91)
at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:76)
at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:54)
at Traccia2014$.main(Rapporto.scala:40)
at Traccia2014.main(Rapporto.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:627)
 17/02/22 15:29:55 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: s3:/tracceale/params/configS3.txt (No such file or directory))
```

I pass the path mentioned "s3://tracceale/params/configS3.txt" from S3 to the function 'fromFile' like this:

```
for(line <- scala.io.Source.fromFile(logFile).getLines())
```

How could I solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using cluster deploy mode, the logs you have included are not useful at all. They just say that the application failed but not why it failed. To figure out why it failed, you at least need to look at the Application Master logs, since that is where the Spark driver runs in cluster deploy mode, and it will probably give a better hint as to why the application failed.

Since you have configured your cluster with a --log-uri, you will find the logs for the Application Master underneath s3://aws-logs-813591802533-us-west-2/elasticmapreduce/<CLUSTER ID>/containers/<YARN Application ID>/ where the YARN Application ID is (based on the logs you included above) application_1487760984275_0001, and the container ID should be something like container_1487760984275_0001_01_000001. (The first container for an application is the Application Master.)

Comment: thank you so much, now I have understood the problem. I have updated my answer, check this out please

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a URL to an object store, reachable from the Hadoop filesystem APIs, and a stack trace coming from java.io.File, which can't read it because it doesn't refer to anything in the local disk.

Use `SparkContext.hadoopRDD()` as the operation to convert the path into an RDD

Comment: ok i'm in. 
I'm trying a new strategy. I put the file into master node with 'put' command. It uploads the file in /home/hadoop/ but this file is unreachable from  slaves I think, infact I get the same error.

Comment: you don't need to do that, S3 will work as a source, just use the hadoopRDD() function to tell spark this is coming from a hadoop compatible filesystem

Answer (score 0):

There is a probability of file missing in the location, may be you can see it after ssh into EMR cluster but still the steps command wouldn't be able to figure out by itself and starts throwing that file not found exception.

In this scenario what I did is :

```
Step 1: Checked for the file existence in the project directory which we copied to EMR.

for example mine was in `//usr/local/project_folder/`

Step 2: Copy the script which you're expecting to run on the EMR.

for example I copied from `//usr/local/project_folder/script_name.sh` to `/home/hadoop/`

Step 3: Then executed the script from /home/hadoop/ by passing the absolute path to the command-runner.jar

command-runner.jar bash /home/hadoop/script_name.sh
```

Thus I found my script running. Hope this may be helpful to someone