# AWS EMR - Upload file into the application master

Tags: apache-spark, aws-cli, amazon-emr

I'm using aws cli and I launch a Cluster with the following command:

```
aws emr create-cluster --name "Config1" --release-label emr-5.0.0 --applications Name=Spark --use-default-role --ec2-attributes KeyName=ChiaveEMR --log-uri 's3://aws-logs-813591802533-us-west-2/elasticmapreduce/' --instance-groups InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m1.medium InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=2,InstanceType=m1.medium
```

after that, I put a file into the master node:

```
 aws emr put --cluster-id j-NSGFSP57255P --key-pair-file "ChiaveEMR.pem" --src "./configS3.txt"
```

The file is located in /home/hadoop/configS3.txt.
Then I launch a step:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id ID_CLUSTER --region us-west-2 --steps Type=Spark,Name=SparkSubmit,Args=[--deploy-mode,cluster,--master,yarn,--executor-memory,1G,--class,Traccia2014,s3://tracceale/params/traccia-22-ottobre_2.11-1.0Ale.jar,/home/hadoop/configS3.txt,30,300,2,"s3a://tracceale/Tempi1"],ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE
```

But I get this error:

```
17/02/23 14:49:51 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/hadoop/configS3.txt (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/hadoop/configS3.txt (No such file or directory)
```

probably due to the fact that 'configS3.txt' is located on the master and not on the slaves.
How could I pass 'configS3.txt' to spark-submit script? I've tried from S3 too but it doesn't work. Any solutions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using "--deploy-mode cluster", the driver runs on a CORE/TASK instance rather than the MASTER instance, so yes, it's because you uploaded the file to the MASTER instance but then the code that's trying to access the file is not running on the MASTER instance.

Given that the error you are encountering is a FileNotFoundException, it sounds like your application code is trying to open it directly, meaning that of course you can't simply use the S3 path directly. (You can't do something like new File("s3://bucket/key") because Java has no idea how to handle this.) My assumption could be wrong though because you have not included your application code or explained what you are doing with this configS3.txt file.

Comment: I need to read configS3.txt from S3 or something else. I pass the path  "s3://tracceale/params/configS3.txt"  to the function 'fromFile' like this:

for(line <- scala.io.Source.fromFile(logFile).getLines())

this function can't read an S3 path so I need to find another strategy

Answer (score 0):

Maurizio: you're still trying to fix [your previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393676/aws-emr-using-spark-steps-in-cluster-mode-application-application-finished-wit).

On a distributed system, you need files which are visible on all machines (which the s3:// filestore delivers) and to use an API which works with data from the distributed filesystem. which `SparkContext.hadoopRDD()` delivers. You aren't going to get anywhere by trying to work out how to get a file onto the local disk of every VM, because that's not the problem you need to fix: it's how to get your code to read data from the shared object store.

Sorry

Comment: how can I use this function SparkContext.hadoopRDD()?

Comment: It's covered in [Spark Programming Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#external-datasets)